# when we try to connect our programme with oracle it is giving error

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, tns, ora-12541

when i try to connect our programme with oracle with this command

`sqlplus crbt/crbt@crbt_new` here crbt is the username and crbt_new is the password.

it is giving error this

```
SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.4.0 - Production on Tue Jan 4 10:32:42 2011
Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

So please tell me where this is wrong

Comment: Can you post your tnsnames.ora file (or at least the definition of the crbt_new TNS alias) and the sqlnet.ora file?  Are you certain that this alias is correct-- does it work on other client machines with the same alias?

Comment: Have you started the listener or configured it to start on boot ? Operating system would be useful too

Answer (score 0):

Below are the possibilities for this:

1) Listener might be down

2) When database is not up, 'TNS: no listener' error appears

3) If the TNS entries are not correct.

Ex: The TNS entry of crbt_new database might have the port number mentioned as 1531, but in real the Database would be listening on port 1521